# Read and Write Ruby

Tags: ruby

Can't seem to get my data to be read as an integer and print out the data, instead gets the 2nd option which is Error: first line of file is not a number.

```
    def write(aFile, number)
  aFile.puts(number)
  index = 0
  while (index < number)
   aFile.puts(index)
   index += 1
  end
end

def read(aFile)
  count = aFile.gets
  if (is_numeric?(count))
    count = count.to_i
  else
    count = 0
    puts "Error: first line of file is not a number"
  end

  index = 0
  while (count < index)
    line = aFile.gets
    puts "Line read: " + line
    index += 1
  end
end

def main
  aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "w") # open for writing
  if aFile  # if nil this test will be false
    write(aFile, 10)
    aFile.close
    aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "r") 
    read(aFile)
    aFile.close
  else
    puts "Unable to open file to write or read!"
  end
end

def is_numeric?(obj)
  if /[^0-9]/.match(obj) == nil
    true
  end
  false
end

main
```

Any help on how to fix this would be great.

Comment: What does `count` contain?

Comment: I am guessing that `aFile.gets` ends with a newline, which causes it to fail  the `is_numeric?` test.

Comment: any idea on how to fix it so `aFile.gets` doesnt end with a newline?

Comment: `aFile.gets.chomp`

Comment: `aFile.gets.chomp` doesnt seem to fix it

Comment: `aFile = File.new("mydata.txt", "w")` that will never be `nil` (or falsey). It always returns a `File` instance.

Comment: @Struggling_Coder Your method `is_numeric?` has `false` as last expression in its body, and hence always returns `false`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is a lack of `return`

```rb
def is_numeric?(obj)
  if /[^0-9]/.match(obj) == nil
    true
  end
  false
end
```

This function ALWAYS returns false. There is no case where it ever returns true. Ruby functions always return at an explicit `return()` and if none is called, then the last line is returned. That means the `true` you have there does nothing. It's simply thrown away and `false` is returned.

A simplified form of this existing function is just:

```rb
def is_numeric?(obj)
  false
end
```

To fix this problem, you need to `return` when it’s true:

```rb
def is_numeric?(obj)
  if /[^0-9]/.match(obj) == nil
    return(true)
  end
  false
end
```

You can also simplify this to:

```rb
def is_numeric?(obj)
  /[^0-9]/.match(obj).nil?
end
```

Also, if you’re using Ruby 2.4+, a more efficient way to do this would be to use the [match?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Regexp.html#method-i-match-3F) method and a negation. `match` sets up some handy MatchData (and backreferences), but since you if you don't need any of that, you can save the overhead by using `match?`, which simply returns a boolean.

```rb
def is_numeric?(obj)
  !/[^0-9]/.match?(obj)
end
```

Another problem is your logic of `count < index`.

```rb
  while (count < index)
    line = aFile.gets
    puts "Line read: " + line
    index += 1
  end
```

Since `index` is 0, the only time `count` will be less than `index`, is if count is less than 0. Perhaps you meant `while (count > index)`?

Notes:

https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2016/12/25/ruby-2-4-0-released/

Comment: The 2nd code block prints out nothing and the 3rd one give errors.

Comment: I’ve updated my answer a little. You didn’t give an example file. What are you expecting to be in this file that’s read? Is it really just a number?

Comment: Thanks i just realized why it wasnt working, it was my while statement,.